# Box<Any> downcast return None in dylib module

Tags: rust

I use dylib as plugin solution. When I call function `register`(in the code below, `fun` is my project name)：

```
let register = plugin.get::<unsafe extern fn(&mut fun::mem::Mem)>("register").unwrap();
unsafe {
    register(&mut mem);
}
```

In dylib's `register` function, `mem.get_mut::<fun::router::Router>("router")` return `None`

But if I use `mem.get_mut::<fun::router::Router>("router")` in `main.rs`. It return `Router` as I want.

I test more and get some result below:

In dylib:

- `mem.get_mut::<String>("test")` work well.
- `mem.get_mut::<fun::Bob>("bob")` return `None`.

In `main.rs`:

- `mem.get_mut::<String>("test")` work well.
- `mem.get_mut::<fun::Bob>("bob")` work well.

**My question:**

**Why downcast_mut return None in dylib if downcast's generic type defined in Main module ?**

mem struct:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Mem {
    pub value: HashMap<String, Box<Any>>,
}
```

get_mut:

```
pub fn get_mut<T: Any>(&mut self, key: &str) -> Option<&mut T> {
    match self.value.get_mut(key) {
        Some(val) => {
            match val.downcast_mut::<T>() {
                Some(value) => Some(value),
                None => None,
            }
        }
        None => None,
    }
}
```

Sorry for my poor description.

**Update:**

TypeId test result:

```
# in dylib's function:
Router TypeId: TypeId { t: 10245301028242226491 }
String TypeId: TypeId { t: 2231836747111135853 }

# in `main.rs`'s function:
Router TypeId: TypeId { t: 11005875220745415326 }
String TypeId: TypeId { t: 2231836747111135853 }
```

**TypeId is different. Any solution for this problem?**

Comment: There isn't enough detail here to give a definitive answer, but assuming you're compiling the components separately: `TypeId`s (which `Any` is internally based on) *are not* stable across compilations.  It's likely returning `None` because each component has a different idea of what the unique ID for `fun::Bob` is, thus they "see" different types.  You can verify this by running `println!("{:?}", ::std::any::TypeId::of::<Bob>());` in both components and checking the output.

Comment: Yes, you are right. TypeId of String is the same. But Router's TypeId is different. See the update. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: @DK.: Any idea of why they appear similar for `String`? Is this an accident, a specificity of `std`, or the key to making it work for user-written types?

Comment: @MatthieuM. it's probably because the std library is compiled only once (when the distribution is prepared), but in this case the type in question is likely compiled twice, even if it is declared in the same crate (once for the dylib, once for the main program).

Comment: dylib is compiled independently, so TypeId would always be different. But I think TypeId should be the same what ever compiled times. This link may be helpful: [http://davidlegare.ghost.io/seeking-compilation-independent-type-ids-in-rust/](http://davidlegare.ghost.io/seeking-compilation-independent-type-ids-in-rust/). But now It seems there is no solution, except that rustc change the way how TypeId generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, up until now (1.10) the `TypeId` is not stable across crates or compilations.

@eddyb just this week landed a [pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/35267) which makes `TypeId` unique cross-crate which will enable your particular usecase.

It is important to note that this stability is not complete; if you read down the comments, for example, you will note that the `TypeId` may change if the compiler version or crate version changes. Still, for a single compiler and shared dependency, it's now stable across re-compilations.

For now, you can either use a nightly compiler, or wait until the next stable version which will contain this patch (1.12 or 1.13 I suppose).